# AC unit not turning on

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, attic

My A/C doesn't come on when I set the temperature on the Braeburn thermostat very low.  Also, the recirculation fan doesn't come on when I set the thermostats fan setting to 'on', as though the indoor unit is not receiving any signal from the thermostat for either cooling or recirculation.

The setup:

- The AC worked at the end of the summer when we stopped using it.
- During the cooler months last year I was crawling around the attic doing work up there (I'm fairly fastidious and careful and I didn't bump anything that I'm aware of).
- I recently had new siding put on my house and the workers let the junction unit next to the outside condenser dangle while they installed the new siding
- I checked everything after the siding work was done (outside lights, AC, etc) and found the AC unit didn't come on
- I've measured 250V on the condenser side of the large fuse in the junction box that was left dangling.  So, I don't think the workers did anything but am mentioning it here in case I've overlooked something.
- I've gone up to the attic where the indoor/fan unit is located and noted the wire connectors between like colored wires (red, yellow, green) are still there and weren't accidentally disconnected.  See pictures below.
- Like colored wires between indoor fan unit and outdoor condenser are still firmly connected as well (red, yellow, brown).
- I've taken pictures of the wiring diagram on the side of the fan unit in the attic which shows RD, BR, GR/BK, WH/BK, WH/BL, YL going to thermostat (optionally, WH/BK and WH/BL tied together.  So 5 or 6 wires to thermostat (this is only AC not heat if that matters).  See pictures below.
- I've gone to the thermostat, disconnected the face unit from the wall and measured 27-27.5 volts White and all the other wires (Red, Yellow, Green).  The thermostat is a Braeburn.  See picture below.

While in the attic I stuck the voltmeter probes into some of the twist-on connectors but didn't measure anything.  Before proceeding to take anything apart, **what voltage should be across these wires going into the unit**:

1. Red (jumpered to another red running towards condensing unit)
2. Yellow (also jumpered)
3. Green (not jumpered)

**Does anyone have any other advice on what to check**?

[image: Brown, Yellow, Red in the bottom center are jumper wires running in the direction of the outdoor condenser unit.]
[image: Wiring diagram on side of indoor Rheem fan unit in attic]
[image: Wiring behind thermostat]

Comment: If I suspected that the wiring had been stressed, I'd undo and redo all the connections, one wire at a time.  Remove the wire nut, check the wiring underneath and replace the nut. Back off the screw terminals, reseat the wires and retighten the screws.